# DNS resolution in VPN?

Tags: vpn, dns

Can someone tell me how a DNS resolution looks like when I'm connected to a company VPN? like what exactly happens if I type `www.google.com` while I'm in the VPN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea the configured DNS server for the network does the job of resolution. However there are several problems associated with this so this article is worth a read:

http://www.isaserver.org/img/upl/vpnkitbeta2/dnsvpn.htm

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the configured DNS server for the network you're connected to does the resolution.